# how do i make an external variable optional? (gcc, c)

Tags: c, gcc, linker, sections

I made a library that contains a main that calls every function in a section, and I want it to work even if the section is empty. How do i do  that?

my code so far is

inside header:

```
#define CONCAT(x,y) x##y
#define CONCATE(x,y) CONCAT(x,y)
#define make_init static void (CONCATE(*init,__COUNTER__))()__attribute__((section("my_init"), unused))=
```

inside main.c:

```
make_init 0;

extern void(*__start_my_init)();
extern void(*__stop_my_init)();

int main() {
    for (void(**initfunc)() = &__start_my_init; initfunc < &__stop_my_init; ++initfunc)
        if (*initfunc) (*preinitfunc)();
    return 0;
}
```

it compiles fine, but when i link the library to a program and i don't do another

```
make_init foo;
```

or another function, the linker says that __start_my_init and __stop_my_init are undefined.

on the other hand, if i don't make it extern it only adds the function inside the library (0) inside the section and not the ones defined in the program that uses the library.

how do i go about making making the section contain a 0 by default and add the functions defined in the program that is linked with the library inside the same section?`

Comment: My are you using a custom init section? There is a standard way to write dynamic library constructors and destructors, and that's as simple as defining the functions with `__attribute__((constructor))`.

Comment: Is the `static` intentional?

Comment: @MarcoBonelli i want to be able to call the functions inside a specific location inside the main, not before the main.

Comment: @kotatsuyaki the `static` is intentional, as i was originally used `__LINE__` instead of `__COUNTER__` and didn't want to be problems when using multiple files, and it doesn't affect anything, as the variable is still stored inside the section. i tested without the static keyword and nothing changed